# How to pop up another page above current page using Angular2?

Tags: angular, components

I have two menu items listed on the left page, the first page named "Dashboard" and the 2nd page named "Resource request", you can switch page via clicking the item. Each page is an independent component.

I want to change the action, add one button on the 1st page, when I click this button, the 2nd page will pop up and floating above current page(Only one item listed on the left page for this design). Is there any solution to achieve this? thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is a modal. various CSS frameworks like [Materialize css](http://materializecss.com/modals.html) or [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/) already support this out of the box.

I don't think you really need to change your Angular code but rather the CSS of your second component to behave as a modal instead of a new page.

Maybe [this example](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modals.asp) can help you get started if you want to build it yourself instead of using a framework

Comment: Thanks, I will have a try first and then give you feedback.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, use modal to do it well.

Comment: @Daisy.Hsu that's great to hear! did you create it yourself or did you use a framework to do it?

Comment: Create modal and design style by myself.